# Strange width behavior with DataGridColumn in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, datagrid, datagridcolumn

if I set a datagrid with 3 fixed width columns everything works as expected (the 3 columns measure 100):

```
<Window x:Class="DataGridTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" >
<DataGrid HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="100" Header="A" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="100" Header="B" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="100" Header="C" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
</Window>
```

If I change one column to Width * when you resize the window making it smaller all of them change their width.

```
<Window x:Class="DataGridTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" >
<DataGrid HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="A" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="100" Header="B" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="100" Header="C" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
</Window>
```

Is this the expected behavior or is it a bug in WPF?

Comment: Just a stab here, but without specifying units, is the 100 interpreted as "100% of available space"?

Comment: @sasfrog: not at all, they are interpreted as 100 device independent units.

Comment: You are right, this is somewhat unexpected, but that's the default behavior..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is how the datagrid works by default: the width you set on the columns is only the original width. And then when you size the datagrid down, it resizes ALL columns, independently of their original widths.

if you want your columns to keep their widths no matter what (and show a scrollbar instead, for instance), you should use MinWidth instead/as well

Comment: Nice to hear that. I wonder why this is not documented on the datagridcolumn.width documentation.

Comment: one of the little perks of WPF ;-) It gave me quite a headache, too... happy to help